# Shell variable $_ not behaving as expected

Tags: bash, io-redirection

What the reason the number of lines differs?

```
$ head -n 100000 ./access.log > ./data/log.sample
$ cat $_ | wc -l
1933424
```

Comment: Also visit [Special Parameters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218271/66803) for bash

Comment: In an interactive context, `!$` does what you wanted, but it won't work in a script IIRC.

Comment: @zwol: Yes. I asked a [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271659/vs-last-argument-of-the-preceding-command-and-output-redirection) about it.

Comment: You should use the `tee` command in your script.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$_` is expanding to `./access.log` (last argument of the last executed command), not `./data/log.sample`.

So you are actually seeing the number of lines of `./access.log`.

The redirection (`>`) is not part of the `head` command as it is done by the shell before the `head` command is even started. Hence with `$_` you would get `./access.log`.

---

From `man bash`:

> ($_, an underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname
>   used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in
>   the environment or argument list. Subsequently, **expands to the last
>   argument to the previous command**, after expansion. Also set to the
>   full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the
>   environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this
>   parameter holds the name of the mail file.

Comment: @J.Chomel I'm not sure what you think is a bug, even jokingly.