# $_ vs !$. Last argument of the preceding command and output redirection

Tags: bash, shell, history-expansion

The question is about special variables. Documentation says:

> `!!:$`
>
> designates the **last argument of the preceding command**. This may
>   be shortened to `!$`.

---

> (`$_`, an underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used  to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the 
>   environment or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the **last argument to the previous command** after expansion. Also set to the full pathname  used to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment 
>   exported to that command.

There must be some difference I cannot catch, because:

```
$ echo "hello" > /tmp/a.txt
$ echo "!$"
echo "/tmp/a.txt"
/tmp/a.txt

$ echo "hello" > /tmp/a.txt
$ echo $_
hello
```

What is the difference?

Comment: !$ is history expansion, not a special variable, so I'd assume that the bash code handles them differently.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer to this question, but: ① The Bourne shell language is one of, perhaps *the*, least internally consistent programming language still widely used today. Attempting to deduce general principles will get you nowhere. You just have to memorize all the special rules. Sorry. ② Note the words "after expansion", immediately after the phrase you highlighted, in the definition of `$_`. That's crucial. It might not explain the difference that puzzles you but it does explain a bunch of other ways `$_` and `!$` are not the same.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`!$` is a word designator of history expansion; it expands to the last word of the previous command in *history*. In other words, the last word of the previous entry in history. This word is usually the last argument to the command, but not in case of redirection. In:

```
echo "hello" > /tmp/a.txt
```

the whole command `'echo "hello" > /tmp/a.txt'` appeared in history, and `/tmp/a.txt` is the last word of that command.

`_` is a shell parameter; it expands to the last argument of the previous command. Here, the redirection is not a part of arguments passed to the command, so only `hello` is the argument passed to `echo`. That's why `$_` expanded to `hello`.

`_` is no longer one of [shell standard special parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02). It works in `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` and `dash` only when interactive, `ksh93` only when two commands are on separated lines:

```
$ echo 1 && echo $_
1
/usr/bin/ksh

$ echo 1
1
$ echo $_
1
```

Comment: One effect of `!$` expansion vs `$_` parameter is that `echo $_` always shows in history as `echo $_`, while `echo !$` shows the value that it was expanded to. E.g. `echo one two` then `echo !$`, then pressing up shows `echo two`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what "only when interactive" applies to. I was just able to do something along the lines of `mkdir -p foo && for f in ${array_of_filenames[@]}; do mv $f $_; done` in a bash script

Comment: This is really about the documentation overloading the word "argument" with two different meanings. `$_` gets the last command line argument that actually went to the executed command though the `execve()` call. That happens after the command line is fully parsed, after all expansions etc. But `!$` looks at words at the command line really early, before much parsing has happened. It does some things like detecting quotes there, but not much else.

Comment: You can see a difference too with e.g. `echo $RANDOM`, where `$_` would contain the actual value passed, and hence `echo $_` would print the same random number again. But `!$` would turn into `$RANDOM`, which would then be expanded as usual, giving a different number. Or with `false && echo bar` where `$_` would give `false` (the last argument to the last executed command), but `!$` would give `bar` (the last word on the last command line).

Answer (score 2):

I found it difficult if not impossible to use parameter substitution directly with `!$`.

For example if I could `wget http://foo.com/my.tar` then `tar xf ${_##*/}` but with `!$` it is not possible without defining an intermediary variable.