# Why can't I use `kill $!` with parameter expansion in Bash, when the most recent process is "notify-send"?

Tags: bash, kill, libnotify, notify-send

According to Bash: [Special Parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218271/66803):

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin

I can utilize this as follows:

```
$ leafpad &
[2] 3962
$ kill $!
```

This works and kills the most recent process (eg. `leafpad`) but for `notify-send` it seems not working:

```
$ notify-send Hello &
[2] 4052
$ kill $!
bash: kill: (4052) - No such process
```

And I have to use `killall notify-osd` in order to kill it.

So, I want to know why `kill $!` doesn't work for `notify-send`? And what is the proper way to kill such a process?

<sub>Note: I know that I can specify the time-out, but this is a different issue.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`notify-send` doesn't run for any length of time: It starts, connects to `notify-osd`, delivers the notification message to be displayed, and terminates.

By the time you run the `kill` command, `notify-send` has already terminated on its own. The notification you're seeing is served by `notify-osd`.

Comment: This is a more clear answer than what I had written just before; I've deleted my post & will add the links here just in case they are useful to Pandya: [notify-osd discussion on Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620).

In short, notify-send is part of `notify-osd`, and is not running by the time you kill it, and also is supposed to only run as "notify-osd" according to [NotifyOSD developer Design Specifications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#System_nomenclature)

Comment: BTW, the OP can prove this for themselves by hitting Enter again between the `notify-send Hello &` and the `kill $!`.  On hitting Enter, the shell should display something like `[1]+  Done                    notify-send Hello` indicating that the job has terminated.