# What does ${#} means in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I could not find any references related to what does ${#} actually means in shell scripting, My rough guess is that it means the last variable passed to an invocation, but not completely sure.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218270/315749 (and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/315749 if you are wondering about `${#}` v. `$#`)

Answer (score 3):

No, it means [number of positional parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), the same as `$#`. For example the following script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo ${#}
```

would print:

```
$ ./script.sh  arg1 arg2 arg3
3
$ ./script.sh  arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
4
```