# '$' predefined shell variable (called as "$$"). What does it hold?

Tags: shell, variable

I had a typo and wrote $$ in a bash script (as argument to echo).  It printed a number (1979).  I tried many times, and all of them printed the same number, so I thought it might have to do with the Unix epoch.  I didn't find any information about it in the bash manual, or in the internet at all.  Then I tried on a basic sh; it printed a different number, 5755, and after closing and opening a new sh, it printed a slightly different number.

What is that variable supposed to hold?  What is the meaning of that number?

Comment: @muru yes it does.  My search foo failed :/. Maybe the special characters don't work very well in the search engine...

Comment: Actually, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218270/341413 is better, even if it's less specific.  The answers to the question you pointed to didn't specify that subshells get the same result.

Comment: That's pretty much how I found the dupe. Search for "bash special variable", find that question, look at the linked ones for a more specific one

Comment: Searching for those can be a pain, and it's not helped by the fact that `$$` and others like it aren't technically _variables_, just _parameters_, the distinction being a bit of hair-splitting. "Variables" are parameters with alphanumerical names (not starting with digits), and only variables can be set with e.g. `var=value`. Also, `$foo` is _parameter_ expansion: it _can_ be used with non-variable parameters too. Though in practice people of course use "variable expansion" to mean the same thing, and e.g. Bash's manual uses the phrase "parameter and variable expansion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of a number of special shell variables. From [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) relating to this:

> `$`
>
> Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell (see [Shell Execution Environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)), `$` shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.

Other special shell variables include `!` (the PID of the most recently started background task), `?` (the exit status of the most recent task terminating), `#` (the number of positional parameters), `*` (the positional parameters, concatenated into a single string), `@` (the positional parameters, as a list), `-` (the current shell options), and `0` (zero; the name of the shell or script).

Also, from the `bash` manual's "Special Parameters" section:

> `$`
>
> Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a `()` subshell, it
> expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the
> subshell.

Other shells will have a similar wording in their manuals.

In short, the `$` variable, whose value you get by typing `$$`, holds the process ID (PID) of the current shell process.

You can double-check this like so:

```
% echo "$$"
85776
% ps -p "$$"
  PID TT  STAT        TIME COMMAND
85776 p1  SN       0:00.19 -zsh (zsh)
```

This shows that `$$` expands to 85776 for my particular shell process, and that this PID does indeed correspond to a `zsh` login shell, which is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

That variable shows you the current shell's PID, or process ID. Every time you echo (or access) that variable in a given shell, it will be the same. Anytime you start a new shell (or a subshell) and access it, it will be different from the original shell.

Comment: The value of `$$` in a subshell is always the same as that of the surrounding shell. If you want the PID of a particular subshell, you will have to use `$BASH_PID`, at least if you're using the `bash` shell.